# In Linux device tree syntax, what happens when duplicate labels appear?

Tags: device-tree

I wonder if it is allowed and by this possible that duplicate labels within a *.dts device tree file appear and if so what happens then?

Does a new label allow to overwrite/redefine the old label, for instance?

To make the question more transparent and clearer I would like to state the question what happens to this example dts data.

```
/dts-v1/;
/ {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <1>;
    chosen { 
        labelname: bootargs = "lalalallal";
        labelname: bootargs2 = "lalalallal";
    };
    aliases { };
    memory { device_type = "memory"; reg = <0 0>; };
};
```

in which the we have a duplicate use of the label `labelname`.

The motivation to this question was the inability to find a clear and crisp documentation on the dts syntax telling that labels need to be **unique**

Comment: Please try to state your problem clearer, it is quite confusing the way it is.

Comment: @Kira Indeed I took your comment and added an example. Also by generating the example I was able to find out the answer myself using the example. Maybe somebody will yet be able to complement , enhance the issue (quesiton/answer) by a reference to a docu on the syntax. The reference to the rule "labels need to be unique"

Answer (score 2):

In a device tree one **must not** use duplicate labels. If doing so anyway and a duplicate is encountered by [dtc](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/dtc.1.html) it will yield an error like this:

```
ERROR (duplicate_label): Duplicate label 'labelX' on 'node' in /path and 'node2' in /path
```

I now just wished to have a reference to add to the documentation that would have made me aware of this "labels must be unique". Maybe some comment or additional/alternative answer can point to this resource I was yet unable to spot :)